# MailCore Errors IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, mailcore

I try to use MailCore in my project, but I get these error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_MailCoreEnableLogging", referenced from:
      -[ImapSync run] in ImapSync.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTCoreMessage", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_CTCoreMessage_$_CTCoreMessageBuisnessMail in CTCoreMessage+BuisnessMail.o
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_CTCoreMessage.myFields", referenced from:
      -[CTCoreMessage(CTCoreMessageBuisnessMail) libetpanDateTime] in CTCoreMessage+BuisnessMail.o
      -[CTCoreMessage(CTCoreMessageBuisnessMail) senderDate] in CTCoreMessage+BuisnessMail.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTCoreAccount", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AttachmentDownloader.o
      objc-class-ref in ImapSync.o
  "_MailCoreDisableLogging", referenced from:
      -[ImapSync run] in ImapSync.o
  "_IfTrue_RaiseException", referenced from:
      -[ImapFolderWorker fetchFrom:to:seqDelta:syncingNew:progressOffset:progressTotal:alreadySynced:] in ImapFolderWorker.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

but all of these methodes are there, I can see them in the MailCoreProject!

I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would check if you have added libMailCore-ios.a to your list of "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".

If so, then the problem could be that the MailCore project was compiled for one device while your main project was compiled for a different device. For instance,

- the MailCore project was compiled for simulator ... the symbols of MailCore were generated for x86 architecture
- your main project was compiled for real iOS device ... so the linker was looking for MailCore symbols for armv7 architecture
- Thus, the linker complained, symbols for armv7 architecture not found

To solve the problem, rebuild the MailCore subproject (build-clean and build) with the same device (or same simulator) as your main project.

Answer (score 0):

These could be number of things. How You added MailCore to Your project? As a static library?

You are missing compiled files for armv7 architecture. Make sure that it's added in "build settings" in MailCore project and then try to build it.
You probably build MailCore for the simulator and now You are trying to run it on device. These have to be separated.

Also, You have to be sure that all libraries which MailCore is using, such as libetpan are compiled properly.

PS: adding MailCore to Your project isn't simple process, but it's worth it. :)